# node.js : function.prototype.method multiple exports inside one file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Noob in JS here.

Let's say I have a js file where the contents are like

```
function a(){}
a.prototype.method1 = function() { ... };
a.prototype.method2 = function() { ... };

function b(){}
b.prototype.method3 = function() { ... };
b.prototype.method4 = function() { ... };

module.exports = new a();
module.exports = new b();
```

In this file, I've function definition.
In the next file, I'm trying to access the methods below

```
var x = require('./file.js');

x.a.method1();   //Not working
x.method1();     //Not working
```

But both types of accessing result in error for me. Can you please help me with steps on how to access the methods correctly?

And I can access those functions if I try to have only 1 export in one file. But I want it to be like this. 2 exports in a same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're *replacing* the `exports` property twice:

```
module.exports = new a();
module.exports = new b();
```

As a result, you're only exporting one thing: an instance of `b`, which has no `method1` on it.

Instead, write to properties on the `exports` object:

```
module.exports.a = new a();
module.exports.b = new b();
```

Then:

```
const x = require('./file.js');

x.a.method1();
// ...
```

or more typically, with destructuring so you don't need `x`:

```
const {a, b} = require('./file.js');

a.method1();
// ...
```

---

All of that said: That syntax is the old [CommonJS module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). I suggest you learn the newer standard syntax, "[ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)" (**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules), added to the JavaScript specification in ES2015:

```
function A() {
}
A.prototype.method1 = function() { /* ... */ };
A.prototype.method2 = function() { /* ... */ };

function B(){}
B.prototype.method3 = function() { /* ... */ };
B.prototype.method4 = function() { /* ... */ };

export const a = new A();
export const b = new B();
```

Also note that I've made the constructor functions start with a capital letter, which is the standard convention in JavaScript.

The import would be:

```
import { a, b } from "./file.js";

a.method1();
// ...
```

To do that, you add `"type": :"module"` to your `package.json` (or use the `.mjs` file extension, see the linked docs for details). Note though that a large number of `npm` packages haven't been updated to support ESM yet (not least because supporting both took a while to nail down and is a bit of a pain), so in some cases you have to jump through some (minor) hoops to use them; [more here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#commonjs-namespaces).

(You might also look at the `class` syntax, which provides a more concise and powerful way to write constructor functions and their associated `.prototype` objects.)

Comment: FWIW, I go into the standard module system in detail in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* (links in my profile if you're interested) and `class` in Chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    a,
    b
}
```

Call it from other file:

```
const {a, b} = require("./file.js");
```